# how do remove enclosing brackets from string?

Tags: c

I have a

```
char s9[7] = "[abcd]";
```

How do i remove the brackets `[]` so that

```
s9 == "abcd"
```

I have tried

```
s9 = s9.Substring(1, s9.Length-2);
```

throws error in cygwin

```
a2v2.c:42:13: error: request for member ‘Substring’ in something not a structure or union
a2v2.c:42:29: error: request for member ‘Length’ in something not a structure or union
```

edit:

i realised my error, i am beginner at c and couldnt differentiate between c and C++ code, regards

Comment: this isn't standard c

Comment: Work through some C tutorials. C and C# are different languages.

Comment: Well at least the errors come from GCC :D

Comment: The condition `s9 == "abcd"` will never be true as long as `s9` is an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone will correct me if I'm wrong, since the C standard I know is a couple of decades old, but as far as I know, C doesn't offer any standard support for string manipulation, and in fact doesn't even officially have a concept of strings.  (Or of object functions, for that matter.)  Instead, C uses pointers, which are much more powerful, but much more dangerous in that you can really mess things up if you don't learn your way around them.

The most important thing, if you want to be a C programmer is that you learn C.  At the very least, you need to look up "string manipulation C" and read any of the pages that pop up.

There are many ways to do what you want.  I think this is one of the faster ones (though it modifies the string you're looking at.  If that matters, choose another way):

```
// trim off the last character
s9[strlen(s9) - 1] = '\0';
// the char * points to the s9 array.  +1 makes it look at 
// the second element, so then substring is the string you need
char * substring = s9 + 1;
```

Comment: Aren't you leaving a byte hanging in the void?

Comment: @Jim How?  s9 is still there if you need it.  And any allocator - whether stack or heap - keeps track of the blocks it assigns.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein actually, a modified `s9` is still there... I'd just drop the pretense of preserving `s9`, forget `substring` and do `++s9`.  +1 for using `strlen`...

Comment: @RichardSitze ++s9 would have worked fine.  I deliberately chose to use an extra pointer to try to make it easier to understand.  Considering OP was expecting a string class, I didn't want to confuse the issue with "an array decomposes to a pointer".

Comment: Using `++s9` would not work, because _arrays are not pointers_.

Answer (score 3):

If it is strictly C, then you will need to use more basic functions (a char[] array has little in common with the string class in C++).  Some of the functions to use might be:

- [`strchr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr):  Find the position of a character (e.g., `strchr( s9, '[')`).  This assumes that it is not a fixed format you are dealing with.  If you know the length and positions, then you could skip this and simply use memmove directly.
- [`memmove`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove): Shift the character left in the array.  In this situation `memmove` would be needed (over `memcpy` or `strncpy`) because the target and destination overlap.

Answer (score 3):

Skipping any checking that the string *actually* begins and ends with those characters:

```
int len = strlen(s9);

for ( i = 0; i < len - 2; ++i )
  s9[i] = s9[i + 1];

s9[len - 2] = '\0';
```

Comment: During the loop? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Shot why am I getting -1?  I'm doing basically the same thing.... :(

Comment: Don't know. Didn't downvote you.

Comment: You fixed it. I meant second call to strlen you used to have.

Comment: Ah. No, `strlen` would not have changed at that point. I changed it after the first draft since calling `strlen()` twice was wasteful.

Comment: But if copied stuff over, the string could be longer:   [abcd] => abcdd]

Comment: That's still 6 characters long. And I was subtracting 2 from it when terminating the string.

Answer (score 3):

```
memmove( s9, s9 + 1, 4);
s9[4] = 0;
```

Comment: Assumes string always contains 4 chars.

Answer (score 2):

```
int len = strlen(s9);
memmove(s9, (s9+1), len-2);  /* can handle overlapping strings */
s9[len-2] = 0;  /* null terminate */
```

Comment: It's not allowed to use `strncpy()` (or `memcpy()`) on overlapping strings

Comment: Downvote reversed. :)

Comment: `*(s9 + 1)` is the character 'a', not the pointer to it. You probably mean: `(s9 + 1)`

Comment: Ugh, you are right...